# C# Алгоритм "Mark and Sweep" в сборщике мусора уже реализован или его нужно самому реализовывать?

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Алгоритм "Mark and Sweep" в сборщике мусора уже реализован или его нужно самому реализовывать?