# Нужно ли самостоятельно реализовывать механизм «Mark and Sweep» или он уже есть в сборщике мусора?

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Допустим, у нас есть код:

```
class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
   Element el1 = new Element();
   Element el2 = new Element(){OtherElement = el1};
   el1.OtherElement = el2;
 }
}
class Element
{
 public Element OtherElement {get; set;}
}
```

Тут нам, чтобы удалить el1 and el2, понадобиться механизм "Mark and Sweep". Но я не знаю, есть он уже в сборщике мусора или нужно ли самому его реализовывать. Почему вообще поднялся этот вопрос? Сборщик мусора работает на основе ссылок: есть ссылка на объект - не трогаем объект, нету - освобождаем память. Но приспособлен ли сборщик мусора к циклическим ссылкам или нужно самому писать механизм "Mark and Sweep"?

Comment: В связи с чем вообще возник такой вопрос? По идее да, GC работает по этому алгоритму, если ничего не путаю. Там ещё и поколения есть, возникающие из объектов, которые пережили чистку.

Comment: Никто не мешает вам [выяснить это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138718/373567) опытным путем. А реализовать можно все что угодно, вопрос - зачем?

Comment: `Mark and Sweep` уже есть https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/garbage-collection.md и в цикличесике ссылки GC тоже умеет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C# Алгоритм "Mark and Sweep" в сборщике мусора уже реализован или его нужно самому реализовывать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160674/c-%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-mark-and-sweep-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be)